# Swift EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sigabrt, exc-bad-instruction

I try to code a game (i use this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkYpoRj-7hA im new in Swift).
Thats my Code so far:

```
import UIKit    
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Image View
    @IBOutlet var ticTac_A01: UIImageView = nil
    @IBOutlet var ticTac_A02: UIImageView = nil
    @IBOutlet var ticTac_A03: UIImageView = nil        
    @IBOutlet var ticTac_B01: UIImageView = nil
    @IBOutlet var ticTac_B02: UIImageView = nil
    @IBOutlet var ticTac_B03: UIImageView = nil        
    @IBOutlet var ticTac_C01: UIImageView = nil
    @IBOutlet var ticTac_C02: UIImageView = nil
    @IBOutlet var ticTac_C03: UIImageView = nil

    //Buttons
    @IBOutlet var ticTacBtn_A01: UIButton = nil
    @IBOutlet var ticTacBtn_A02: UIButton = nil
    @IBOutlet var ticTacBtn_A03: UIButton = nil    
    @IBOutlet var ticTacBtn_B01: UIButton = nil
    @IBOutlet var ticTacBtn_B02: UIButton = nil
    @IBOutlet var ticTacBtn_B03: UIButton = nil        
    @IBOutlet var ticTacBtn_C01: UIButton = nil
    @IBOutlet var ticTacBtn_C02: UIButton = nil
    @IBOutlet var ticTacBtn_C03: UIButton = nil        

    @IBOutlet  var resetBtn: UIButton = nil
    @IBOutlet  var userMessage: UILabel = nil

    var plays = Dictionary<Int, Int>()
    var done = false;
    var aiDeciding = false;

    @IBAction func UIButtonClicked(sender : UIButton){
        userMessage.hidden = true;

        if !plays[sender.tag]   && !aiDeciding && !done {
            setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
        }            
        checkForWin()
        aiTurn()
    }

    func setImageForSpot(spot:Int, player:Int){
        var playerMark = player == 1 ?  "x" : "o"
        plays[spot] = player

        switch spot {

        case 1:
            ticTac_A01.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

        case 2:
            ticTac_A02.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

        case 3:
            ticTac_A03.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

        case 4:
            ticTac_B01.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

        case 5:
            ticTac_B02.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

        case 6:
            ticTac_B03.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

        case 7:
            ticTac_C01.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

        case 8:
            ticTac_C02.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

        case 9:
            ticTac_C03.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

        default:ticTac_B02.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        }            
    }

    func checkForWin(){}
    func aiTurn(){}        

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

First i i get the „Thread 1: signal SIGABRT“ with this Output:

```
2014-07-21 10:26:21.709 Swift-Tac-Toe[3264:107207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_TtC13Swift_Tac_Toe14ViewController 0x7f8160ca0f00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ticTac01.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001010a3055 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102b5da1c objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001010a2c99 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001014b67a3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100fed950 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000101bdb58d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000101a42898 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000101a42f49 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000101a431ba -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000101a4364f -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000101964d79 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000101965112 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 276
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000101971e70 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010191cc31 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2673
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010191f5cc -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1222
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010191e5ac -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 19
    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000104357263 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100fd909c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100fce805 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100fce5c5 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100fcda06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010191dfc2 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000101920cf8 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  Swift-Tac-Toe                       0x0000000100c224fd top_level_code + 77
    24  Swift-Tac-Toe                       0x0000000100c2253a main + 42
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001030ce145 start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

After Debug > Continue i get **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)**.

and thats it.

Anyone can help me here?

Comment: Hi,  I fixed your stack trace to make it readable.  The best way to format stack traces is to format them as code.

Answer (score 6):

Read the crash log output; it says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_TtC13Swift_Tac_Toe14ViewController 0x7f8160ca0f00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ticTac01.'

So the problem is that you have configured something (possibly an object in a XIB or Storyboard) to access `ticTac01`, which doesn't appear to be defined in your class.  My guess is that that might have been an earlier name for one of the variables you *do* have?